# App Centre not showing applications other than installed apps

Tags: appcenter

Whenever i open APPCENTRE, there are no apps shown. Only the installed apps are displayed. I tried to even search for new applications, but nothing is displayed.
how can an i install Libra Office?

Comment: Also take a look here (down part) to fix appcenter - https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/18685/16827

Answer (score 1):

Open your `Terminal` application then type:

`sudo apt install libreoffice`

More information: [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LibreOffice)

Edit:

Recent updates fix the app center problem. Basically you have to do:

```
sudo apt update
```

Then

```
sudo apt install packagekit
```

[More info about the fix](https://medium.com/elementaryos/important-update-released-501c9d9f28b)

Comment: i guess I really fried by App Center ...