# Update error - signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available

Tags: release-juno, updates, system, apt

I installed a few days ago(monday I think) elementary OS 5.0 Juno. Everything went really good, I'ma pretty experienced Linux user, I've been using ubuntu,elementary os and linux in general for quite a lot. However, today when I ran `apt update` this happend: https://pastebin.com/3Peg9c9M. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please execute these commands in the terminal, and let me know what if you find. `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`  `sudo apt-get update`  `sudo apt-get clean`  `sudo apt-get install --fix-missing`

Comment: `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` returns nothing `sudo apt-get update` the first time returned: `Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
`, `sudo apt-get clean` fixed the previous error, but returned nothing, `sudo apt-get install --fix-missing` returned that there are no packages to install, then I ran apt update again and the error was still there

Comment: Do you had update / upgrade / installation process ongoing when you executed the apt-update from above?

Comment: Nope, I only had chrome running and I opened a new terminal window when I saw the reply. Already done that, same error

Comment: I have added the commands in this [pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sJgmhgvsNy/), Please execute the above commands and let me know. Here we are manually adding missing public keys and updating OS. Please let me know what you find.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hhF4X8GcnN/

Comment: Please take a look at this answer, [https://askubuntu.com/a/386003/907048](https://askubuntu.com/a/386003/907048)

Comment: I can't instal that program.... I get this when I try to run apt update: `E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please execute `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <yout_key_string>`
For example, `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32`. And run `sudo apt update`.

If that doesn't work or end up with error, please try to download and install keys manually from [keyserver.ubuntu.com](https://keyserver.ubuntu.com). Search your key string like this,

[image]

and copy every thing from the BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY line to END PGP PUBLIC KEY line. Save the text in a text file. Then please execute `sudo apt-key add <file_name.txt>`. For example if save the key contents in a text file name key, then `sudo apt-key add key.txt`. Now run `sudo apt update` from the terminal or go to [appcenter](/questions/tagged/appcenter) and check for updates.

If this also didn't worked, please execute `cp /etc/apt/trusted.gpg{~,}` to  restore trusted.gpg from APT automatic backup. And then run `sudo apt update` to check if the issue still persists. If yes, please  execute `sudo rm /etc/apt/trusted.gpg && apt-key update` to delete and re-create it with the keys for the Ubuntu archive. Run update now.

If you face problem with [appcenter](/questions/tagged/appcenter), maybe there's no [curated apps](https://appcenter.elementary.io/) there, then please verify if your source list has elementary OS ppas. If your sources list don't have these,

```
[patches.list] ppa:elementary-os/os-patches
[elementary.list] ppa:elementary-os/stable
[appcenter.list] deb http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic main
```

Please add them,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/os-patches
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
```

And add `http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic main` at the end of the source.list file.

Please execute `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` to open sources.list.
Hopefully this will fix your problem.

Comment: I'm really sorry to bother you again, but apparently the elementary repos aren't working anymore. When I open the appcenter, or I try installing the elementary-sdk package, nothing shows up.

Comment: Let's [talk on chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92361/discussion-between-hasan-and-matt-diamond).

Comment: can you get on chat pls

Comment: I have updated the answer. Glad your problem is solved. Have a nice day!